# Is $-1$ a unit in every ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Is $-1$ a unit in every ring? More precisely, take $-1$ as an element of the ring $\mathbb Z$. $-1$ is a unit in $\mathbb Z$ because it divides every element of $\mathbb Z$. There's a ring homomorphism $\varphi$ from $\mathbb Z$ to every ring $R$.

Is $\varphi(-1) \in R$ a unit in $R$? More generally, do ring homomorphisms preserve units?

Do ring homomorphisms $\varphi: R_1 \longrightarrow R_2$ induce group homomorphisms from the group of units of $R_1$ to the group of units of $R_2$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$-1$ is certainly a unit, because $(-1)(-1)=1$.

A ring homomorphism $\varphi\colon R_1\to R_2$ send units to units: if $u$ is a unit in $R_1$, with inverse $v$, then
$$
1=\varphi(1)=\varphi(uv)=\varphi(u)\varphi(v) \\
1=\varphi(1)=\varphi(vu)=\varphi(v)\varphi(u)
$$
proving that $\varphi(u)$ is a unit in $R_2$. The induced map between the groups of units is obviously a group homomorphism, because $\varphi$ preserves products.

<sub>Note. If ring homomorphism are not supposed to preserve the identity, the result is generally false.</sub>